# Is there a clean way to extract nested properties from an application.properties using @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-properties

I was looking to move away from `@Value` annotation to using `@ConfigurationProperties` primarily because I ended up having too many properties so adding all of them in the target class seemed to clutter the class with Value annotations and if I were to mark them as final then the constructor would have a long list of parameters.

`application.properties`

```
sms-gateway:
  sms:
    authorization:
      token: xyz
    username: abc
    password: pass
    url: http://example.com
    lynx:
      cmd: lynx -dump -display_charset=utf-8 <%= @sms-gateway_sms_url %>
    via:
      cmd: true
  admin:
    status:
      url: http://admin.example.com/status
```

`SmsService.java`

```java
...

@Value("${sms-gateway.sms.url}")
private String url;

@Value("${sms-gateway.sms.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${sms-gateway.sms.password}")
private String password;

and so on ...
```

As an alternate `@ConfigurationProperties` allows you to have a dedicated class that groups together properties. However, you have end up binding it to a common namespace for the properties to bind with the fields of the class being annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

`SmsConfig.java`

```java
...

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sms-gateway.sms")
public class SmsConfig.java {
  
  private final String username;
  private final String password;
  private final String url;
  ...
}
```

However to add other nested properties you would need to add classes for each of the nested properties along with `@NestedConfigurationProperty` to indicate that's a nested property. This could again get a bit out of hand if there are many nested properties.

My question is two fold -

1. Is there a cleaner way to implement this without having to involve inner classes and binding the nested properties under a field in the same common namespace.
   For instance in the above example - How can we bind the authorization token or lynx command properties without having to add a single field inner or completely new classes.
2. Is there a way to change the field names and bind those to the property names so say if I want a different name `private final String SmsGatewayUsername` and want to bind this to the username property ?

Thank you and much appreciated for any comments and answers !

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you cannot change the structure. You can however bind a `Map<String, Object>` if you don't mind losing the bean typing.
2. Properties are bound by bean properties, which are determined by the public getters and setters, not the field names. You could add a setter with any name you like, and with any logic you want inside it. To get really complex, you could write a custom bean property binder, but I don't recommend it for your use-case. The default one does things like converting kebab-case to camelCase.

Both your property names and your configuration classes should follow a logical structure, and it's far easier to deal with if they're the same structure.